# StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1

Tags: c#, windows

Am trying to call a webservice inside Windows StoreApp Windows Phone 8.1, but for some reasons it returns an empty string,when I drill down to the details I get something like "StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1"
Please see the code

```
private async Task<string> WCFRESTServiceCall(string methodRequestType, string methodName, string bodyParam = "")
    {
        string ServiceURI = "http://localhost:34826/WCFRestDemo.svc/rest/" + methodName;
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(methodRequestType == "GET" ? HttpMethod.Get : HttpMethod.Post, ServiceURI);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bodyParam))
        {
            request.Content = new StringContent(bodyParam, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"); 
        }
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        string returnString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return returnString;
    }
```

I can access the webservice directly from the browser and get the response using the same url

Comment: You prolly need to replace `localhost` with the `webservice ip-address` though

Comment: Thanks, but its locally hosted on my machine and its not connected to any network so I cant get the ipaddress

Comment: Yes, but `localhost` points to the device itself. You need to replace localhost with the internal ip of your server. Otherwise your phone app will try to locate the server on it's own device

Comment: Ok, it makes sence, but please how do I get this ip address from my laptop

Comment: [WIN] + [R]  => cmd [ENTER] => ipconfig [ENTER]